# Azure alerts can be send to an event hub

Tags: azure

I am looking if there is an option to send a cure alerts to the event hub and current on Prem system to read the events to create an action like creating a ticket for the event, however on alert section, there is no option for that, as I am new to azure wondering is there a workaround.

Comment: Take a deep breath, read your question again like someone who does not have the context that you have and try to improve the question by adding more context of what exactly it is you try to accomplish because for me I only have a vague idea of what you might mean.

Comment: Also, how did you end up choosing for an Event Hub over, say event grid or (storage) queue?

Comment: I am putting my objective as I said am looking how I can send the alert event to my ticket system. Not sure what context need to be add to the question.  I am new so asking what option or best practice available.

Comment: What is a cure alert? In your title you are mentioning azure alerts. Do you mean azure monitor alerts? How does an event look like, what volume do you expect and what size?

Comment: If it really is an azure monitor alert you can send to to a webhook triggered azure function that will forward it to eventhub. But again, I wonder how you did end up choosing an event hub. There might me better options.

Comment: Thanks Peter for response, I don't have to use eventhub, I just need something working best on azure for alert trigger. So to give you example, let say alert trigger because vmss unable to scale up some reason and alert trigger and I want that alert to create ticket on our system, our system able to read kafka message currently, that is I taught if I use event hud probably easy since eventhub use Kafka topic,  Anyways all I am looking based on vmss alert to create ticket when alert trigger and the message deliver to event system and the ticket system to act based on the message.